# Javascript Objects, What am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, object, javascript-objects

I have the following code from a coding exercise. When I try to submit it I get a

> SyntaxError: Unexpected string

```
var movieObj = {
"Toy Story 2": "Great story. Mean prospector.",
"Finding Nemo": "Cool animation, and funny turtles."
"The Lion King": "Great songs."
};

var getReview = function (movie) {
    if (movie in movieObj) {
        return movieObj[movie]
    } else {
        return "I don't know!"
    }
};

getReview("Toy Story 2") //expected = "Great story. Mean prospector."
getReview("Toy Story") //expected = " don't know!"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Question should probably be closed as it's just a simple comma typo and there is no particularly interesting future value to this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're actually just missing a comma for the second item of the movieObj object. replace the second line with 
`"Finding Nemo": "Cool animation, and funny turtles.", 
/* Notice the comma */` It should work fine after that.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot a comma after "... turtles" Object properties are separated with `,`

Answer (score 0):

You were missing a comma in your `movieObj` for `"Finding Nemo"` In addition, you were also missing some semi-colons `;`

```
var movieObj = {
    "Toy Story 2": "Great story. Mean prospector.",
    "Finding Nemo": "Cool animation, and funny turtles.",
    "The Lion King": "Great songs."
};

var getReview = function (movie) {
    if (movie in movieObj) {
        alert(movieObj[movie]);
    } else {
        alert("I don't know!");
    }
};

getReview("Toy Story 2"); //expected = "Great story. Mean prospector."
getReview("Toy Story"); //expected = " don't know!"
```